# Vapor There are difficulties in interpreting the code and 401 error appears when performing

Tags: ios, swift, server, vapor

I am practicing the vapor server after watching this tutorial at https://github.com/thomashbailey/vapor-auth. As you can see from the code, createUser performs well, but if you try to log in, 401 error pops up and I ask you a question.

I'm sending a server request to postman, how should I send it?
[image]

Isn't it a code that gives tokens when you log in? I don't know. I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems the server is a demo for the [HTTP Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617).

You have to create a user first providing a password.

Once this is done, when accessing a protected resource you need to authenticate the request via providing a HTTP "Authorization" header.

This can be done by "preemptively" setting the request header "Authorization" in your request as follows:

Combine user name and password separating it with a colon ":" and base64 encode it. Then set the "Authorization" request header as follows shown in the pseudo code:

`Authorization: "Basic" + " " + base64("\(username):\(password)")`

Another way is to handle the `401 (not authorised)` status code through analysing the "WWW-Authentication" response header, which comes along a 401 when you did not set the "Authorization" header. This is explained in detail in the mentioned RFC.

Note that HTTP clients - including Postman - do aid in setting up the Basic Authorization Scheme. You will find that easily in Postman itself.

**Edit**

You may now notice, that you have to send the username and password in clear, every time you send a request.

This should ring bells of course. In fact, Basic HTTP Authentication is deprecated due to its vulnerabilities. You should of course use HTTPS, to prevent sending the data in clear over the wire - nonetheless, sending a password with every request should make us gripes.

A more modern and more secure scheme is using a bearer token, for example in OAuth or OIDC.

Comment: what string is in username and password ??

Comment: @ga-yo Username and password is specified by you. You pass these values in the request when you create your user. This corresponds to a user registering for the service. _After_ a user has been created, you set the Authorization request header in Postman with each request. Note that the whole process only partly "simulates" a real application with a client and service.

Comment: then when i request the login. "localhost" + "/users/login" and body... is it alright..? i can't understand TT

Comment: @ga-yo You use POST `/api/users/` to create a user. You set username and password in the parameters in the body. You have to provide the username and password. Make sure you remember them. ;) But Postman can do this for you, too.

Comment: Isn't it possible to sign up as /api/users/ and log in as /api/users/login? There's always an error 401 ...

Comment: POST `/api/users/ ` cannot (should not) fail with 401. It does not require you to set the Authorization header. It may fail with another error, though. You might want to debug the code  and check where there is a problem.

Comment: oh,, that's my fault... sorry but current error is in /api/users/login ... 401 . .. ..

Comment: In Postman, you can setup Basic Auth for the `/login` endpoint. Enter the username and password from the user you created with `/api/user`. If this does not work - you need to debug the server and find out ;)